# Creating a custom web service for Dynamic Navision

Tags: web-services, dynamic, navision

I am new to Dynamic Navision .On just going through the Dynamic Navision Solution I could find certain in-built Web Services.

1. Can those Web Services be customizable .
2. If so how can I make it possible.
3. Can I create a new Service with new Object Id .

I have searched for resources,but couldn't find any .It would be really helpful if someone suggest me with a good resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, more specifically you're looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd339004.aspx

- Creating a codeunit from within Microsoft Dynamics NAV.
- Exposing the Web service.
- Verifying the Web services availability.
- Consuming the Web service from a console application that is created
  in Visual Studio

Just make sure you have

- Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2009 with a developer license.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to give: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd355036.aspx a read.